# HQL query filter criteria to fetch child records is returning more rows than required

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have created three tables for one-to-many mapping
1) CashMemo
2) StockRecord
3) CashMemo_StockRecord.
For each CashMemo entity there can be more than one StockRecord entities.
Following is my hql query

```
String sql = "select cm from CashMemo cm join cm.stockRecords s where s.stockTypeId=" + stockTypeId;
```

The result of this query is returning rows with that specific stocktypeid and also those rows which have the cashmemoid similar to earlier rows returned.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: That's expected: if you ask: give me all countries which have a state named "Alabama", you'll get the USA, right? Now if you ask the USA: give me your states: it will give you back all its 50 states, and not just Alabama, right? If you want to only get back states named Alabama with their country, you should ask the database: give me all the states named Alabama, and the country that they belong to.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the `CashMemo_StockRecord` table unless there is a many-many relationship involved here as well. A more proper HQL may be `select from CashMemo cm where cm.stockRecords.stockTypeId = :stockType`.  That is, the join expression may be compounding your result.  Remember to set the `stockType` parameter.

Comment: @dan no, that would be invalid JPQL. And a join table for OneToMany association makes perfect sense: it's the default mapping of unidirectional OneToMany associations, BTW.

Comment: @JBNizet, From your explanation I require all countries with state name as Alabama. Likewise all cashmemo with stocktypeId as something. So isn't my hql correct.? Why is it returning those states which has USA country associated to it?

Comment: Because you're not selecting states. You're selecting countries. And once you have the countries, you ask them: OK, what are your states?

Comment: @JBNizet, Let me know whether I have understood it correct. So you mean I should have bidirectional mapping and I should query StockRecords (from your example States) instead of CashMemo(Countries from you example). Currently I am having unidirectional mapping from CashMemo to Stockrecords which is One-to-Many.

Comment: No, you don't necessarily need the association to be directional. You can just use `"select cm, s from CashMemo cm join cm.stockRecords s where s.stockTypeId = :stockTypeId"`. That will return a list of object arrays, where the first element is the cach memo, and the second one is the stock record with the requested type.

Comment: Here is another way of doing the HQL (my prior was JPQL was indeed incorrect): `from CashMemo c join c.stockRecords s where s.stockTypeId = ?` then of course set the parameter for the Stock Type you're looking for.  This will give you the corresponding CashMemo having that Stock Type record.

Comment: Both queries give me list of object array. This should solve my problem, However, making the association bi directional will give me list of StockRecords associated with CashMemo. Don't you think this is better?

Comment: Making an association bi-directional adds convenience as you navigate the data model but can result in decreased performance during loads and saves. As with all code, there's trade-offs.